# Best way to move my Gameobject smoothly?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I've got an issue when I try to **move smoothly a Gameobject**.

I receive **every second through a TCP Protocol** a position, where my Gameobject have to move. So I have my **start position**, my **end position**, I can calculate the **distance** between the two position , and I know my Gameobject have to move with a constant speed to my end point in **1 second**.

I try 3 solutions that are : **Learp**, **MoveToward** and **SmoothDamp** , but none of them work, my Gameobject just teleport from point A to point B every time.

Here's what I try in my code (*my Gameobject is referenced in a dictionnary*, *my Gameobject are planes*) :

```
// Distance between my 2 points
float step = Vector3.Distance(planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position, new Vector3((float)newPlane.X, (float)newPlane.Afl / (3.2808f * 1852f), (float)newPlane.Y));
//Use of Lerp
//planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position, new Vector3((float)newPlane.X, (float)newPlane.Afl / (3.2808f * 1852f), (float)newPlane.Y), step);
//Use of MoveTowards
planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position, new Vector3((float)newPlane.X, (float)newPlane.Afl / (3.2808f * 1852f), (float)newPlane.Y), step);
//Use of SmoothDamp
//planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform.position, new Vector3((float)newPlane.X, (float)newPlane.Afl / (3.2808f * 1852f), (float)newPlane.Y), ref newPlane.GroundSpeed, 1);
```

The code is a function that is called in my Update this way :

```
void Update () {
        lock (threadLock)
        {
            // Message receive from my TCP Protocol
            while (q_orders.Count > 0)
            {
                switch (q_orders.Dequeue())
                {
                    case OrderType.trackmovedevent:
                        aircraftMajInfos(q_args.Dequeue()); // My function to move my Object
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you calling MoveTowards in Update() or any other loop ?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it in my Update.

Comment: use lower values for last argument for Lerp and SmoothDamp. The way Lerp works is it takes point A and point B, then it looks at the value S in final parameter and returns point C. Basically S represents normalized value between A and B, meaning S=0 returns A, S=1 returns B, S=0.5 returns middle point between A and B and so on... In other words, ratio of Distance(A, C) and Distance(B, C) is equal to ratio of S and (1 - S). So in your case making S 1 will always return the destination point, resulting in "Teleport". Make that value lower than 1.

Comment: also, to make Lerp frame-rate independent u can just multiply the S value with Time.deltaTime. So that the guy playing at 60fps does not have faster transitions than a guy playing on 30fps.

Comment: With this solution, How can I be sure I will go to point A to point B in 1 second ? I try to put the third parameter at 0.1*Time.deltaTime, and it moves very slowly and not smoothly :(

Comment: oh no, if you multiply by Time.deltaTime than you might as well increase S because Time.deltaTime is equal to 1/FPS which is veeery low number. Try 10 * Time.deltaTime or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its better to use a tween engine , like http://dotween.demigiant.com/.

If you install Dotween then you can simply use

```
transform.DOMove(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration);
```

You can also set Ease for tweens. or use Oncomplete fucntions;

```
transform.DOMove(new vector3(1 ,0 , 1) , duration)
    .SetEase(Ease.OutCubic)
    .OnCompelete(() => { shouldClose = true; });
```

Comment: Whoa, this is pure fire dude ! Resolve all my problems with the frames ! But I'm not sure the speed is constant, it seems not, there's an acceleration and deceleration during between each point.

Comment: you can set Ease type to Linear

Answer (score 3):

I must say that you have understand all three functions totally wrong. They should be called in multiple updates, not just once.

In this situation I recommend `MoveTowards`. Because `SmoothDamp` doesn't move the object at a constant speed, and to use `Lerp`, you need to caltulate the ratio between the two points (note that you CAN move the object constantly if you add the amount to the t parameter every fixed update).

Here's a code snippet I wrote for the MonoBehaviour of your gameobject

```
const float moveTime = 1;
Vector3 target, step;

void Update () {
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target,
        step / moveTime * Time.deltaTime);
}
// Call this method to set the new target (the currently received position from network)
public void SetTarget (Vector3 positon) {
    target =  positon;
    step = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target);
}
```

`Time.deltaTime` is the interval between updates (where the `Update ()` function called)

Comment: Ok now i get it why my object teleport, it's because I call it just once, when I should call it multiple times, thanks, but to call my function, I use a boolean in my update, so I don't have any other solution than calling it during only 1 frame, is there a way to do the MoveTowards ? If it's not clear I 'll update my code.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil So you found a solution for the problem; but next time you ask a question, remember to truncate  the code lines that are too long, those codes are very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Create a new script "ObjectMover" (maybe not the best name) and apply it on the Game Objects that you want to be able to move.
- In the script create a public method: MoveToNewPos(Vector3 newPos) which stores the new position that you are aiming for with this object.

Inside the Update method of "ObjectMover" use lerp or calculate the stepping yourself using step / moveTime * Time.deltaTime to move towards the wanted new position and only adjust the speed to you desired look and feel.

From your "main" script do theObjectIWantToMove.GetComponent().MoveToNewPos(newPos); and it will smoothly move there.